# Getting error 405 method not allowed on client calls using Webclient

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

I am making multiple client calls to other Microservices from the Weblux app using Weblcient. There are over 500 elements in a flux and each element makes several api calls(each publisher makes 10 client calls) to other microservices. For some reason , which I dont know, for some requests , I am getting the error 405 method not allowed, even though the request never changes for every item in the publisher.

```
Mono<Map> responseMono = this.webClientBuilder.baseUrl(URI).build()
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                .log()
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(1, Duration.ofMillis(200)));
        return responseMono ;
    }
```

This is the method used by all the items inside the Flux to make a client call. I have tried shifting weblcient calls to different scheduler , so that they dont share the same thread pool as of the application server, but this hack didnt solve the issue.

Comment: 405 means that the HTTP request _method_ doesn't match, e.g. GET/POST/PUT/etc. In your case, you're sending a GET request while the server must expect another method.

Comment: If you try those requests that fail directly using Postman or curl do they work?

Comment: @sp00m There is nothing wrong with the request and its method, every item of the flux calls the same request . But for some items, the request fails and give this error.

Comment: @JoãoDias yes, apparently the same request logged, gives the output perfectly in postman or in browser

Comment: That is very strange indeed. Could it be that the service you are calling is not able to keep up with so many requests and for some weird reason it returns a 405 (it shouldn't, but we never know)?

Comment: @JoãoDias the client service has no rate limiter or something which stops them from serving the request. If it had , it would give service unavailable error.

Comment: @JoãoDias this is a very strange error indeed. Unable to wrap my head around it. It has certainly to do with increase in no of items in the flux which are making the calls. As for smaller items, this issue never arises

Comment: Are you able to see the requests reaching the service you are calling?

Comment: are you creating a new instance of the `WebClient` for each individual HTTP request? If so, this seems unusual though I would never think that this could lead to intermittent 405s

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen No, I am not creating a new instance of Weblcient for each reqst. I am just calling the above method which doesnt create a new instance.